# Convert a list and list of tuples to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of tuples

```
data = [('2015-10-08', '2016-07-17'), ('Alex', 'Jerry'), (5, 6)]
```

And I have a list, this list contains column headings.
`title = [Date , Name, Age]`
With this list and list of tuples I want a dictionary of dictionaries

This is the expected output

```
output = {'1' : {'Date': '2015-10-08', 'Name': 'Alex', 'Age': 5},
          '2' : {'Date': '2016-07-17', 'Name': 'Jerry', 'Age': 6}}
```

I tried

```
output = {}
for i in range(len(title)):
    output[i+1] = {title[i]: ",".join(data[i])}

print (output)
```

I am getting

```
{1: {'Date': '2015-10-08','2016-07-17'}, 2: {'Name': 'Alex','Jerry'}, 3: {'Age': 5,6}}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: output = {}                                                                                                                                        for i in range(len(title)):                                                                                                                 
      output[i+1] = {title[i]: ",".join(data[i])}                                                                                      print (output)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use loops to build easy to read code. But the Pythonic way would be to use *comprehensions*:

```
result = {str(i + 1): {t: data[j][i] for j, t in enumerate(title)}
          for i in range(len(data[0]))}
```

It gives as expected:

```
{'1': {'Age': 5, 'Date': '2015-10-08', 'Name': 'Alex'},
 '2': {'Age': 6, 'Date': '2016-07-17', 'Name': 'Jerry'}}
```